# My application was rejected due to Google Maps?

Tags: appstore-approval, google-maps-sdk-ios

Today my app got reject i don't understand problem.

Rejected because:

> 10.6 - Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected

With comment:

> 10.6 Details
>
> Your app’s location feature is not integrated with the built-in mapping functionality, which limits users to a third party Maps application.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to give users the option to launch the native Apple Maps application.

What i need to do? I should add Apple Maps in my app and give the user a choice?
Why they do not require such other applications.

A few words about my application: It’s social network that displays the users on map

[You can see main screen with Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ppg0.jpg)

Comment: Are you also using the Google Maps URL scheme to open the Google Maps app, perhaps on a button or something?

Comment: That might be something new they are trying to enforce. Talk to your reviewer via the resolution center and if your arguments won't work or reviewer keeps silent, file a dispute there. You better use iTunes connect forums to discuss this with "public", and as Apple says - "don't take it to the press, talk to us first".

Comment: i need the answer of this too....

Comment: Is the query cleared?

Answer (score 2):

they say: 
"to give users the **option** to launch the native Apple Maps..."

what you can do is show an action sheet with 3 options:

1. google maps
2. waze
3. maps

the user will choose ...

one of the option shoukd be maps of Apple
implement the maps option as follow:

```
    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 100
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span),
        MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: motType = MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
    ] as [String : Any]
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil))
    mapItem.name = placeName
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside iTunes Connect, I simply questioned the rejection, asking them why this was required, and stated that I have business logic related to Google Maps. After two days the app got accepted.